# Citation numbering not updating

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a problem updating my citation numbering. For example, if I go and change a citation in the beginning of my document I would expect the numbering to be automatically reordered. I am using the IEEE referencing style which makes use of chronological numbering for references in the paper.

I do the normal update order of latex bibtex latex latex and the numbering is still not reordered correctly. The only way I have found around this issue is to delete all temporary files and rebuild the document. This gets very annoying when I have to repeatedly delete tempory files.

Does anyone have a way to update citation numbering?

Thanks

Comment: As it normally works fine there is something special either in your document or your workflow. So you will give more information. E.g. a minimal example and the log and the blg.

Comment: What do you mean by "chronological numbering"? By publication year? Please advise. Please also state which IEEE bibliography style you use -- there's more than one of them around.

Answer (score 1):

This is the output I get from

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2015,
}
@article{riter,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2014,
}
@article{entist,
  author={S. C. I. Entist},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\cite{uthor}, \cite{entist}, \cite{riter}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So you see that the references are sorted in the order they appear in the text.

If I change `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` into `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}`, I get

[image]

You see that, in this case, references are sorted alphabetically.

---

There are also `IEEEtranN` and `IEEEtranSN` for author-year citation style. The output from

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2015,
}
@article{riter,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2014,
}
@article{entist,
  author={S. C. I. Entist},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{uthor}, \cite{entist}, \cite{riter}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

is, again in order of citation,

[image]

If `IEEEtranSN` is used, the references are sorted alphabetically

[image]

#### Note

The `filecontents*` environment is used just for making the example self-contained. Use your own `.bib` file in the usual way.